# Probability of failure needed

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

There are 38 numbers on a wheel.
I pick 5 numbers and maintain those 5 numbers for 35 spins of the wheel. What is the probability that 1 of my 5 numbers will NOT be selected within the 35 spins/rounds? I know the math equation and answer for this is 0.0072 failure rate...NOW...
the answer I need now is...how many times can I expect my 35 round system to succeed before failing?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: "How many times can I expect my 35 round system to succeed before failing?" What is success and failure here?

Comment: You are wrong about the failure rate. The 0.0072 is the success rate. So I expect it to fail the first time you try it. Or are you asking "How many spins can I do before it fails?" It is going to be much less than 35 spins

Comment: It will fail at about 5 spins

Comment: The expected number of spins until none of your numbers shows up is ${38\over33}\approx1.15$ if that's what you are asking.